# Upload de Video para Youtube com Asp .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, youtube

Estou tentando fazer uma integracao com o YouTube, mas estou recebendo o error

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}
```

Eu liberei a minha api key conforme a imagem abaixo e estou testando esse codigo abaixo, alguem poderia me ajudar mostrando o que esta faltando?

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("VideoToYoutube", "AIzaSyBiXxL5nS6IjYRGJUhDdaYdWGqAGwOvD8A");

            YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

            Video newVideo = new Video();

            newVideo.Title = "Teste";
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("teste", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
            newVideo.Keywords = "Teste";
            newVideo.Description = "Teste";
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("teste, teste",
              YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);


            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\Users\\tadriano\\Documents\\streaming\\mov_bbb.mp4", "video/mp4");

            try
            {
                var createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                var teste = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }


            return View();
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nos HTTP referrers, não é necessário colocar a URL de onde esta chamando?

Comment: Eu coloquei localhost, *localhost*, 127.0.0.1 e nada... dai deixei em branco para esse ultimo teste.

Answer (score 0):

Se alguem precisar um dia eu resolvi alterando o login conforme abaixo:

```
 public static Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService AuthenticateOaut(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {

            string[] scopes = new string[] { Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,  // view and manage your YouTube account
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload};

            try
            {
                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                             , userName
                                                                                             , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore("Daimto.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

                Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService service = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService(new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Web client 1",

                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }

        }
```

E na console eu criei uma chave conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]